# Constructors for templates that do not have default constructors

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that currently has a constructor that takes no arguments. The issue is that in some cases the class that is being used in the template does not have an empty constructor which gives compile errors.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
     public:
     T Thing;
     int number;
     A():number(5) {}
 };


  class B
  {
       public:
       int a;
       B(int _a):a(_a) {}
  }

  A<int> a1; // This is fine
  A<B> a2; // This is not fine since B has no default constructor
```

I’ve thought of possibly using adding a second constructor which takes a ref to T, and then using enable_if to remove the parameterless constructor if T does not have a default constructor, but I’m not sure if that would work. Are there other options?

Note that I do not want to add a default constructor to class B because I don't want to leave an instance of B in an unknown state.

Comment: If you're "not sure if that would work", perhaps you should try it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This seems like an X, Y problem.

Comment: I havent tried it because I’m not sure what the enable_if would look like.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Whats an X Y problem?

Comment: Making a default constructor is the easy solution. Why won't you do it? Just add something like `B() { a = 0; }`

Comment: @bpeikes see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)

Comment: @bpeikes look at [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) and [`std::is_default_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - In my specific case class B in question should not have a default constructor as that would put it in an unknown state.

Answer (score 0):

Spoke to some people and did more research and found the solution.
Making the default constructor templated by a constexpr static member.
Here it is:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
     T Thing;
     int number;
     static constexpr bool HasDefaultConstructors = std::is_default_constructible<T>;

     // This removes the default constructor if T does not have one
     template<bool HDC = HasDefaultConstructors, typename std::enable_if<HDC, int>::type = 0>
     A():number(5) {}

     A(const Thing &t):T(t) {}
 };
```